# Simple string concat example fast in Java 7, slow in Java 8

Tags: java, performance

I have a little class that demonstrates some timing characteristics of different ways to concatenate strings (StringBuilder vs. plain string contatenation).  Irrespective of the relative timings of each strategy, I noticed particular performance behavior with Java 6, and then later Java 7, and now Java 8.

I had first written it with Java 6, and I was impressed with the large improvements I saw with Java 7.  I had assumed that Java 8 would show similar performance.  However, when I run this on my Win7/64-bit laptop, I find that the Java 8 numbers are even slower than my Java 6 numbers.

It's entirely possible I'm seeing issues with Java 6 and 7 where the JVM is removing the code I'm testing at runtime (a common obstacle to microbenchmarks), but I just don't know.

I'm going to show my perf numbers for the three runs, and then I'll include the source code.  Note that the test has a hefty warmup pass, which hopefully should result in all classloading and JIT work finishing before the timing runs.

Also note that the relative timings in Java 6 and Java 8 are "consistent".  For instance, I expect tests 2 and 3 to be the two fastest, 2 sometimes faster than 3, or vice versa.  The Java 7 timings are all much lower than that, and mostly about the same, so it's possible I have an issue with the Java 7 JIT cutting out too much code.

```
Java 6:
stringBuilder0:499
stringBuilder1:260
stringBuilder2:262
stringBuilder3:180
stringBuilder4:184
stringBuilder5:210
stringBuilder6:286
stringBuilder7:287
stringBuilder8:203
stringBuilder9:248

Java 7:
stringBuilder0:66
stringBuilder1:269
stringBuilder2:57
stringBuilder3:57
stringBuilder4:57
stringBuilder5:57
stringBuilder6:299
stringBuilder7:57
stringBuilder8:57
stringBuilder9:57

Java 8:
stringBuilder0:714
stringBuilder1:367
stringBuilder2:368
stringBuilder3:279
stringBuilder4:271
stringBuilder5:318
stringBuilder6:415
stringBuilder7:406
stringBuilder8:308
stringBuilder9:349
```

Here are the two classes that generate this data.

StringBuilderTests:

```
package timings;

public class StringBuilderTests {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilderTests  stringBuilderTests  = new StringBuilderTests(args);
    stringBuilderTests.go();
}

public StringBuilderTests(String[] args) {
}

private void go() {
    final String  str1    = "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789";
    final String  str2    = "abcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghi";
    final String  str3    = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    final String  str4    = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";
    final String  str5    = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";

    System.out.println("Running warmup pass.");

    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < 20000; ++ ctr) {
    testStringBuilder0(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5);
    testStringBuilder1(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5);
    testStringBuilder2(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5);
    testStringBuilder3(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5);
    testStringBuilder4(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5);
    testStringBuilder5(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5);
    testStringBuilder6(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5);
    testStringBuilder7(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5);
    testStringBuilder8(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5);
    testStringBuilder9(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5);
    }

    int     iters   = 10000000;

    System.out.println("Starting timing runs.");

    new TimingContainer(iters, "stringBuilder0", new TimingTest() {
    public void run() {
        testStringBuilder0(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5);
    }
    }).run();

    new TimingContainer(iters, "stringBuilder1", new TimingTest() {
    public void run() {
        testStringBuilder1(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5);
    }
    }).run();

    new TimingContainer(iters, "stringBuilder2", new TimingTest() {
    public void run() {
        testStringBuilder2(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5);
    }
    }).run();

    new TimingContainer(iters, "stringBuilder3", new TimingTest() {
    public void run() {
        testStringBuilder3(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5);
    }
    }).run();

    new TimingContainer(iters, "stringBuilder4", new TimingTest() {
    public void run() {
        testStringBuilder4(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5);
    }
    }).run();
    new TimingContainer(iters, "stringBuilder5", new TimingTest() {
    public void run() {
        testStringBuilder5(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5);
    }
    }).run();
    new TimingContainer(iters, "stringBuilder6", new TimingTest() {
    public void run() {
        testStringBuilder6(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5);
    }
    }).run();
    new TimingContainer(iters, "stringBuilder7", new TimingTest() {
    public void run() {
        testStringBuilder7(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5);
    }
    }).run();
    new TimingContainer(iters, "stringBuilder8", new TimingTest() {
    public void run() {
        testStringBuilder8(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5);
    }
    }).run();
    new TimingContainer(iters, "stringBuilder9", new TimingTest() {
    public void run() {
        testStringBuilder9(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5);
    }
    }).run();
}

private void useit(String str) {
    System.out.print(str.charAt(0));
}

public static String testStringBuilder0(String str1, String str2, String str3, String str4, String str5) {
    String  result  = null;
    result  = result + str1;
    result  = result + str2;
    result  = result + str3;
    result  = result + str4;
    result  = result + str5;
    return result;
}

public static String testStringBuilder1(String str1, String str2, String str3, String str4, String str5) {
    StringBuilder   sb  = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(str1);
    sb.append("-");
    sb.append(str2);
    sb.append("-");
    sb.append(str3);
    sb.append("-");
    sb.append(str4);
    sb.append("-");
    sb.append(str5);
    return sb.toString();
}

public static String testStringBuilder2(String str1, String str2, String str3, String str4, String str5) {
    return new StringBuilder().
        append(str1).append("-").append(str2).append("-").append(str3).append("-").append(str4).append("-").append(str5).
        toString();
}

public static String testStringBuilder3(String str1, String str2, String str3, String str4, String str5) {
    return new StringBuilder(str1).append("-").append(str2).append("-").append(str3).append("-").append(str4).append("-").append(str5).toString();
}

public static String testStringBuilder4(String str1, String str2, String str3, String str4, String str5) {
    return str1 + "-" + str2 + "-" + str3 + "-" + str4 + "-" + str5;
}

public static String testStringBuilder5(String str1, String str2, String str3, String str4, String str5) {
    return new StringBuilder(160).
        append(str1).append("-").append(str2).append("-").append(str3).append("-").append(str4).append("-").append(str5).
        toString();
}

public static String testStringBuilder6(String str1, String str2, String str3, String str4, String str5) {
    StringBuffer   sb  = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(str1);
    sb.append("-");
    sb.append(str2);
    sb.append("-");
    sb.append(str3);
    sb.append("-");
    sb.append(str4);
    sb.append("-");
    sb.append(str5);
    return sb.toString();
}

public static String testStringBuilder7(String str1, String str2, String str3, String str4, String str5) {
    return new StringBuffer().
        append(str1).append("-").append(str2).append("-").append(str3).append("-").append(str4).append("-").append(str5).
        toString();
}

public static String testStringBuilder8(String str1, String str2, String str3, String str4, String str5) {
    return new StringBuffer(str1).append("-").append(str2).append("-").append(str3).append("-").append(str4).append("-").append(str5).toString();
}

public static String testStringBuilder9(String str1, String str2, String str3, String str4, String str5) {
    return new StringBuffer(160).
        append(str1).append("-").append(str2).append("-").append(str3).append("-").append(str4).append("-").append(str5).
        toString();
}
}
```

TimingContainer:

```
package timings;

public class TimingContainer {
private int         iterations;
private String      label;
private TimingTest  timingTest;

public TimingContainer(int iterations, String label, TimingTest timingTest) {
    this.iterations = iterations;
    this.label      = label;
    this.timingTest = timingTest;
}

public void run() {
    long startTime  = System.nanoTime();
    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < iterations; ++ ctr) {
    timingTest.randomize();
    timingTest.run();
    }
    long    endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long    totalns = (endTime - startTime);
    System.out.println(label + ":" + (totalns / iterations));
}
}
```

**Update:**

TimingTest:

```
package timings;

public abstract class TimingTest {
public abstract void run();
public void randomize() {}
}
```

Comment: Try using [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) for your benchmarking.

Comment: Added missing TimingTest class.

Comment: your `testingStringBuilder#` isn't a `StringBuilder` in the sense of java's implementation, you should be using that if you want efficient string appending.

Comment: My Java 8 test is running faster than Java 7.

Comment: @Rogue, I don't know what "testingStringBuilder#" means.  In any case, I'm just comparing different ways of concatenating strings, not specifically the StringBuilder class.

Comment: @Sotirios - what platform are you running that on?

Comment: test 2,3 and 5 produce the same bytecode as test 4.

Comment: @Blank - Yes, that's part of the point I'm trying to show with this test.

Comment: Oh, I get it.  My Java 8 was 32-bit, not 64-bit.  The 64-bit one is faster than Java 7.  Never mind.

Comment: Without making sure that your benchmark doesn't get optimized away, you're just wasting time, anyway. Using JMH or Caliper is really not that hard and not only makes your benchmark more correct, it also makes it simpler and more accessible to others.

Comment: Acknowledged.  Now that there's two of you recommending it :) , I took a look at it (JMH).  Looks very comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

The discrepancy was that I was comparing 64-bit Java 7 with 32-bit Java 8 (The Eclipse in Spring Tool Suite 3.5.0 apparently won't work with the 64-bit Java 8, which is why I had the 32-bit Java 8 distro).

Once I ran the test with 64-bit Java 8, I got more reasonable results.

In addition, I learned about [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/), which is handy for writing and running microbenchmarks that need to be accurate.

Comment: Are you referring to tests 6-9? I thought i was pretty clear in what i'm doing here, in comparing the various strategies to dispel misconceptions. As you can see, all the others are using StringBuilder directly or indirectly.

Comment: Ah, apologies for that, I saw StringBuffer and as there is no real reason to still use that, I came to the wrong conclusion.

Comment: I agreed with you, that's why I wrote the test.  The more common misconception I was trying to deal with was the idea that plain string concatenation is somehow less efficient than StringBuilder.

Comment: It is less efficient. But you need a very long string consisting of a lot of components that are not part of the short time heap in the Java VM. Not something you would see every day. And processors are *so fast* nowadays. Even with just plain byte code I get over 125 MiB/s AES encryption speed. A string concat... yawn.

Comment: Plain string concatenation produces bytecode virtually identical to the same code directly using StringBuilder.

Comment: Most of the time this kind of concern is not even at the back of my  mind. I use string builders within loops or when the strings are spread out over multiple lines. For anything else `+` or even `String.format()` will do. Readability and semantically correct applications are much much much much much more important.

Comment: Which makes misguided use of StringBuilder even more ironic.  The better code (using string concatenation) is just as fast (faster, if you didn't realize you could send the first segment to the StringBuilder constructor), shorter, and easier to read.  They're going to nag us about moving this to cat, so EOD.